# Scala Spark: how to create new columns for a flattable with names out of value of column 1 and column2 and value of column3 as content

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, pivot, flatten

How is it possible to transform a dataframe with the following
original form:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  #1|   A|   1|  C3|  I4|
|  #1|   A|   2|  D3|  J4|
|  #1|   A|   3|  E3|  K4|
|  #1|   B|   1|  F3|  L4|
|  #1|   B|   2|  G3|  M4|
|  #1|   B|   3|  H3|  N4|
|  #2|   A|   1|  O3|  U4|
|  #2|   A|   2|  P3|  V4|
|  #2|   A|   3|  Q3|  W4|
|  #2|   B|   1|  R3|  X4|
|  #2|   B|   2|  S3|  Y4|
|  #2|   B|   3|  T3|  Z4|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

to the following
desired form:

```
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|col0|col1_A_col2_1_col3|col1_A_col2_2_col3|col1_A_col2_3_col3|col1_B_col2_1_col3|col1_B_col2_2_col3|col1_B_col2_3_col3|col1_A_col2_1_col4|col1_A_col2_2_col4|col1_A_col2_3_col4|col1_B_col2_1_col4|col1_B_col2_2_col4|col1_B_col2_3_col4|
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  #1|        C3        |        D3        |        E3        |        F3        |        G3        |        H3        |        I3        |        J4        |        K4        |        L4        |        M4        |        N4        |
|  #2|        O3        |        P3        |        Q3        |        R3        |        S3        |        T3        |        U3        |        V4        |        W4        |        X4        |        Y4        |        Z4        |
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

in order to create a flattable.

Comment: Looks like a pivot but not in the classical sense. Can there  be 1 .. 4 as well as 1 ..3 ?

Comment: What if value C in col1, implies we get a new column I presume as well?

Comment: Need to cogroup or something along those lines getting K,V's. Not sure about new col vals leading to new col names, seems would get a very wide RDD and sparse

Comment: trying to generate feature names?

Comment: needs better explanation